# Is it possible to tail -f output to a single line?

Tags: tail

`less` has an option `-S` or `--chop-lines` which prevents lines from wrapping and shows output as one line (often extended beyond screen).

Is it possible to do this with `tail -f`?

The `tail` man page doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not the easiest, and it won't change the output width if you change the screen width.

```
tail -f myfile.txt | sed -n -e "s/^\(.\{$COLUMNS\}\).*/\1/p"
```

EDIT: the new one below is easier to type and don't break lines with a tab (thx for the comments):

```
tail -f myfile.txt | expand | cut "-c1-$COLUMNS"
```

Alternatively, do you know you can press F inside less?

> "F" key :     Scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is reached.  Normally this  command  would be  used when already at the end of the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a file which is growing while it is being viewed.  (The behavior is similar to the "tail -f" command.)

Comment: nice! both answers work perfect. I wondered if it was necessary to pipe output into tail. I can see myself using the less option alot more, easier to remember, can show line number and can access gzipped files, thanks!

Comment: Or `cut "-c1-$COLUMNS"`. Note that it doesn't work properly if there are tabulations or escape sequences or combining characters, or double-width characters. Another approach is to use `tput rmam` to tell the terminal to stop wrapping (for those that support it) or use a terminal that doesn't wrap like [terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/)

Comment: `less -S +F file` works wonderfully, thanks!